# Translated HTML elements into Jquery but can't see them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to practice JS and Jquery better by creating most of my code in JS.
I tried to search and implement thismethod but came out empty handed.
I will attach the original HTML and then my attempt at it in Jquery:

HTML

```
 <div class="mainContainer col-md-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="checkBoxes">
        <span class="recipePicContainer">
            <img class="recipe" src="../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg" alt="Cocktail">
            <div>Cocktail</div>
        </span>
        <ul class="recipes">
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
           <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
var main = function() {
    $(document).ready(function () {

       var $checkBoxes = $('<div>',{class: "checkBoxes"});
       var $recipePicContainer = $('<span>', {class: "recipePicContainer"});
       var $img = document.getElementById("recipe");
       var $div = $('<div></div>');
        $('.mainContainer').append($checkBoxes);
            $($checkBoxes).append($recipePicContainer);
                $($recipePicContainer).append($img);
                $($recipePicContainer).append($div).append('Cocktail');
        $('.recipePicContainer').click(function () {
            $(this).next('.recipes').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');

        });
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks good. what failed? and you dont need a nested $(document).ready, main() would do it.

Comment: Is the HTML the result of the jQuery or is it before the jQuery runs. What's up with `$('<div>',{class: "checkBoxes"});`? That's jQuery? If your attempt to convert to plain JS is the this jQuery, I don't think one line is a really good try.

Comment: What does the console tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/xg5r72xt/

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

     var $checkBoxes = $('<div>',{class: "checkBoxes"});
     var $recipePicContainer = $('<span>', {class: "recipePicContainer"});
     var $img = document.getElementsByClassName("recipe");
     console.log($img);
     var $div = $('<div></div>');
      $('.mainContainer').append($checkBoxes);
          $($checkBoxes).append($recipePicContainer);
              $($recipePicContainer).append($img);
              $($recipePicContainer).append($div).append('Cocktail');
      $('.recipePicContainer').click(function () {
          $(this).next('.recipes').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');

      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer col-md-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="checkBoxes">
        <span class="recipePicContainer">
            <img class="recipe" src="../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg" alt="Cocktail">
            <div>Cocktail</div>
        </span>
        <ul class="recipes">
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
           <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Code Problem**

var $img = document.getElementById("recipe");

**Changed code explanation**
Element with ID recipe doesn't exists, instead I have used class "**recipe**" from **image tag**.

I believe that's one of the issue.

Comment: Hey there, thanx for the fix.

Comment: The problem is now my image file isn't located correctly anymore it's on the bottom of the page instead of in the correct div. I also seem to have trouble with shrinking my HTML and were not really doing that here

Comment: @DanEker Please create a fiddle with updated code. Will definitely help you.

Comment: Hi, tried it again. I'm getting Cocktail written twice and the JS one isn't doing much, plus again the Cocktail div is over the image, and it needs to be the other way arund (once clicked on the img the ul opens)